# install SDK 24-32 for godot

Tags: godot

I am in need download SDK (24-33) to build apps on godot. I followed some instructions on gg and found a way to download SDK 34. I use `android studio` and have edited it to API 29. However, in dir `C:UsersforneAppDataLocalAndroidSdkbuild-tools` there is only `34.0.0`.
I removed API 34 and replaced ddoss API 29
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ojvk.png)

I'm not sure if API 29 must have 29.0.0, but that's the only step I understand here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/setup-sdk. I just want to download sdk 24-32 and don't necessarily need to use `Android studio`

Answer (score 0):

To manage your SDKs with Android Studio go to:

`Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Android SDK`

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

And manage your SDK installations.

I suggest you to use Android Studio because as you can see it helps you choose all SDK versions you need to install, with SDK tools also.